# How to Boot to Recovery mode on a Lenovo tab M8 FHD Tablet?

Tags: recovery-mode, lenovo

The questions says it all.

This is what I know.

- Pressing & holding the vol+ button while pressing Power - Boots into
  fastboot.
- Pressing & holding the vol- button while pressing Power -
  Boots into download.

The question is how can I boot into Recovery Mode?

Comment: No it should be Vol Up + Power like for every Mediatek device (Vol Dn is fastboot=download=bootloader) ask in that thread https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/lenovo-tab-m8-fhd-tb-8705f-how-to-root-t4049691?goto=newpost

Comment: Vol up + Power brings me into the Download mode. (The screen is blank). This is confirmed from when I rescued my device VIA Lenovo's Smart and Rescue Assistant.

Comment: check the chinese factory mode maybe you can reach recovery mode from that menu https://www.devicesfaq.com/en/reset/lenovo-tab-m8-fhd

Comment: I'm looking to be able to boot to recovery when the power is off. I @alecxs I've seen the link you supplied but there it gives the same info to hold down power + the vol - or power and the vol +.. As I'm writing this I thought how about trying to hold down both the vol buttons. I will try it and get back here with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access recovery mode on this device do the following.

1. Hold down **both** volume buttons while turning on the device with the power button.
2. As soon as the device goes on release the power button but continue holding the volume buttons.
3. Hold the volume buttons till it enters into recovery mode.